# ORDER BY not working in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

This won't work and i'm getting an error from the ORDER BY param for some reason?

```
if($selected_radio == 'city')
{
    $query = "SELECT name FROM City WHERE name LIKE $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3 ORDER BY name ASC";
    $result = pg_prepare($conn, "findCity", $query);
    $result = pg_execute($conn, "findCity", array($text, $limit, $offset));

    while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $i += 1;
    }
}
```

Sorry about the way it looks I'm fairly new to this site and not sure how to correctly post code :/

Comment: Can you include the exact error message?

Comment: To format code, indent it by 4 spaces or select it and click the `{}` button.

Comment: I'm not receiving an error message for some reason?

Comment: @JoshValdivieso You should be, so you need to investigate that too. It's really important that statements that fail report error messages so you can act on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got your clauses in the [wrong order](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-select.html) - ORDER BY goes before LIMIT and OFFSET.

From the docs:

```
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT [ ON ( expression [, ...] ) ] ]
     * | expression [ AS output_name ] [, ...]
     [ FROM from_item [, ...] ]
     [ WHERE condition ]
     [ GROUP BY expression [, ...] ]
     [ HAVING condition [, ...] ]
     [ { UNION | INTERSECT | EXCEPT } [ ALL ] select ]
     [ ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC | USING operator ] [, ...] ]
     [ LIMIT { count | ALL } ]
     [ OFFSET start ]
     [ FOR { UPDATE | SHARE } [ OF table_name [, ...] ] [ NOWAIT ] [...] ]
```